# Уточняющий оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в скобках? Если бы предложение было построено чуть-чуть по-другому: *регуляторы, использующие, также как и регуляторы прямого действия, энергию регулируемой среды*, то оборот нужно было бы выделять обязательно. А если он стоит перед причастным оборотом?

Появились регуляторы, также как и регуляторы прямого действия (,) использующие энергию регулируемой среды, но с  усилителями, началось производство регуляторов косвенного действия, содержащих регулирующие клапаны и использующих для своей работы дополнительные источники энергии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятой не нужно, imho. А "так же" пишется раздельно в данном случае.

> Появились регуляторы, так же как и регуляторы прямого действия
>   использующие энергию регулируемой среды, но с усилителями, началось
>   производство регуляторов косвенного действия, содержащих регулирующие
>   клапаны и использующих для своей работы дополнительные источники
>   энергии.

Ещё на мой взгляд, предложение лучше разбить на два:

> Появились регуляторы, так же как и регуляторы прямого действия
>   использующие энергию регулируемой среды, но с усилителями. Началось
>   производство регуляторов косвенного действия, содержащих регулирующие
>   клапаны и использующих для своей работы дополнительные источники
>   энергии.

Comment: Спасибо. Про _"так же"_ чего-то пропустила. Это ведь не _"тоже"_.

Comment: Рад стараться. :) Да, это означает *"таким же образом"*.

Comment: Можно узнать, что такое imho? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А-а, imho расшифровывается как ‘in my humble opinion’, то есть буквально "по моему скромному мнению". "Бывает" ещё *imo* — то же, только без скромного. =)